# ownCloud Server with Docker - configuration

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, setup, owncloud

TL;DR :

1. Is it advisable to run ownCloud from Docker for a productive system?
2. How can I configure ownCloud within Docker according to my needs (publish domain, ensure data persistence, adjust security settings)?
3. Is it advisable to setup ownCloud manually (install DB, install ownCloud, adjust config)?

---

I have setup a PC with Ubuntu Server 18.04, and I wanted to install ownCloud on it. On the [ownCloud website](https://owncloud.org/download/) I found three installation methods:

- Tarball
- Docker
- Appliance

I decided to install it via Docker as it seems easy and resource friendly. I followed the [installation instructions](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.1/admin_manual/installation/docker/)  and everything worked as expected. Docker installed MariaDB and Redis on the fly.

Next I wanted to make some configurations.

- Publish the service to the internet (I have a domain and a dynamic DNS server which forwards the domain to my dynamic IP address).
- Ensured that the data is persistently stored on the server.
- Adjust the security settings.

I couldn't find some good sources on how to change the configuration. As far as I see the [ownCloud documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.1/admin_manual/) only gives advice for the 'old school' installation.

Answer (score 0):

Before publishing the service I would suggest to put an Nginx container in front as a reverse proxy. A well configured Nginx proxy will add an excellent security layer in between your Owncloud and the jungle out there.

In case you want to do this, you can use this Nginx+Letsencrypt [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt) to even use HTTPS to connect to your Owncloud. Good configuration tutorials to get started can be found [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-compose-nginx-and-letsencrypt-setting-up-website-to-do-all-the-things-for-that-https-7cb0bf774b7e) and [here](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71).

In any case, to configure the Owncloud server you can use the Owncloud docker image [available variables](https://github.com/owncloud-docker/base#available-environment-variables) and mount any required configuration files from your host into the Owncloud container.